# How to relate tables in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have two different tables and I want to relate those tables.
`users` and `friends` ... AND that why I came here, to find an answer :)

**Users Table:**

[Users Table http://3.1m.yt/_p1s7MC.png](http://3.1m.yt/_p1s7MC.png)

**Friends table:**

[Friends table http://2.1m.yt/CVMMWmB.png](http://2.1m.yt/CVMMWmB.png)

(I need 10 reputations to post imgs so don't even talk about).

Comment: The phpMyAdmin documentation has a whole section about relations (there are two ways you can view relations; Relation View and Designer). You can learn more at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/relations.html

Answer (score 0):

You can related users and friends this way

```
select a.user_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.username, a.friend_id ,
        c.firstname, c.lastname, c.username
from Friends as a 
inner join users as b b.id = a.user_id
inner join users as c c.id = a.friend_id;
```